# Passing the form action attribute to a Partial View

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a partial view that I am using from 2 different forms. In order to use jQuery validation I would like to use the  tag instead of the Html.BeginForm helper. This means that I should specify the action attribute myself just like ASP.NET MVC 2 does when I call the Html Helpers. My questions are:

1. How can I do it?
2. Are there better ways to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its relatively easy,  simply write your form tag as follows:

```
<form id="myform" method="post" action='<%= Url.Action("myAction") %>'>
```

If you are calliing the partial from separate places this is the easiest way to achieve what you want

Comment: But my problem is that the action can be "Create" or "Edit" and the partial view does not know which of them. Should I use ViewData to send the Action from the controller?

Comment: Just a clarification the <form> tag is part of the PartialView.

Comment: If you don't know what the action will be, then yes, pass that in the viewmodel or viewdata into the partial